# Controlling the return for a freshly created jquery widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

I have created a jquery plugin that is very simple for now and is not stateful, but since I plan on making it stateful later, I used jquery widget. For now, only the _create function has any code in it. What I've found out through experimentation is that when the widget is called, the jquery object returned is unchanged from the previous object in the chain.

```
$('.myClass').myPlugin().someOtherMethod();
```

At the end of .myPlugin(), it is still $('.myClass') that is selected.

Well, for most plugins, that is actually fine. However, in this particular plugin, I'm wrapping the selected element with a new tag and I'd like to return the wrapper instead. That is I'd like to return this.element.parent().

Trying to write a return statement in the _create function does not seem to work and in all the examples I've seen, _create never have a return statement. How would I solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can, using the widget system. I'd suggest instead not using it, or not having it return the wrapper. Having it return the wrapper can potentially cause other issues. For example, if your plugin creates events, where are the events defined? on the wrapper? on the original element? what happens if the user binds the events to the original elements before using the plugin vs binding the events after using the plugin?

Comment: Good point. This is an area I'll have to look into. I'll probably have to manually examine the events and bindings and transfer them to the wrapper in some cases.